# change string content in another method in java

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm trying to write simple code when user write his name in another method than it display his name
the problem that is string name keep staying null and it doesn't change

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name="";
        saisir(name);
        System.out.println("your name is "+name);
}
    static String saisir (String title){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("write your name");
        String name = s.nextLine();
        return name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, methods are passed by value, which means the String you sent as a parameter won't be affected by the changes inside the method (although you didn't actually change it :P) . It uses a reference of it. When you change it inside method, you actually create a new String, but your actual reference is still pointing to the initial one.
If you want the changed name you should make the assignment in the main() method like other answers are suggested.

```
name = saisir();
```

Since you also don't need the parameter there.

Comment: i understand it better now thanks for you.

Comment: @code this answer has an inaccuracy: the method does not use “a copy of it”. The String object is passed to the method, not a copy of the String. The important thing is that assigning a different value to the parameter within the method has no effect of the variable used when calling the method.

Comment: @Bohemian Right, I edited the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Code this:

```
name = saisir(name);
```

Or better:

```
name = saisir();
```

and delete the `title` parameter since you don’t use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the name, but not keeping it. You are passing a title, but not using it. Let's fix both of those. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = saisir();
    System.out.println("your name is "+name);
}
static String saisir() {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("write your name");
    return s.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time and your help i appreciate it <3

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "";
        name = saisir(); //set "name" equal to the String returned by saisir()
        System.out.println("your name is " + name);
    }

    static String saisir() { //there is no need for this method to take any parameters
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("write your name");
        String name = s.nextLine();
        return name;
    }
}
```